# Drumstick choices for electronic drums

Tags: electronic-drumset, drum-stick

Beginner drummer here. I just bought an electronic drum set and am wondering about how to choose the best sticks.  Some articles I read ([including this one](http://thehub.musiciansfriend.com/drum-buying-guides/how-to-choose-the-right-drumsticks)) talk about different tip shapes and how they make different sounds. 
For example, "barrel tips have a larger contact area for a broader, more diffuse tone." I am thinking that since these are elctronic, the tip shape probably won't have the effects mentioned in the article. Am I correct in thinking that?

**What then should be the main influencing factors on choosing sticks?**

I just bought a pair of 7ANs (with nylon tips).

Answer (score 4):

When it comes to electronic drums, aim for the sticks that feel best for you. While you're not currently using an acoustic drum set, you won't need to worry about the differences in tone between nylon tips, barrel tips, etc. Especially if you're a beginner, you'll just want to find a pair that's most comfortable to you. I use American Classic 5A's when I play acoustic or electric drums, they just feel best to me.

Answer (score 3):

Many of the considerations in choosing a drumstick do not apply when playing solely on an electronic set.  However, there are a few considerations.

First, the most obvious characteristic of drumsticks to most people is the size.  You don't have to care about how the size of the stick you choose affects the volume, but it's a good idea to stay with a drumset stick; a marching stick is liable to cause extra wear-and-tear to your set.

Similarly, as far as materials, you probably want to stay with wood, but which wood doesn't matter (except for your preferences).

Tip is mostly irrelevant, because the sound is generated purely by the machine brain.  Some people like to avoid nylon tips because they find they pop off easily, but I've personally never had a problem with them.

Answer (score 2):

Plastic tipped sticks will preserve your drums a little better than wood. If you chip the wood it could rip through mesh or cut the rubber. Just don't mix the sticks you use on an acoustic kit with your E-kit sticks and you won't have this problem.

Buy a brand new pair of sticks that you like and use those exclusively on your E-kit and nothing else.

Vic Firth is the bomb and I don't use any other sticks personally. Steve Gadd sig series is basically the only stick I buy now.

I personally use a wood stick on my E-kit because I don't care that much about damage; I like the sound better (I play a hybrid E-Kit with real cymbals) and plastic tips sound tinny on real cymbals.